# Binding an ETree element to a kivy Property so it automatically updates

Tags: python, data-binding, kivy

What would be the best way to bind an ETree XML element's text to a kivy property so that it automatically updates when the XML value changes, if that's possible.

I tried just linking them in the kv file, which worked to get the Label's text I was using to show the XML element's text value during startup, but it didn't react to any changes in the XML after that point.

This is likely a simple question, but I don't know how to use the python-side bind functions as I've just been doing it all in the kv file.  I tried to find a good explanation of the way to use the bind function but couldn't, so if you have one that you'd rather point me to that would also be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a function which updates the label periodically. See python code below.

```
class UpdatingLabel(Label):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(UpdatingLabel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1)

    def update(self, *args):
        self.text = file_text
```

you need to update file_text to point the correct part in your xml

Comment: That's what I figured it would have to be.  I was kinda hoping that I wouldn't have to write a function that updates it for each label and textinput I have, but if that's the only way, so be it.
I'll wait a few more hours and then mark this correct if nothing else comes up.

Comment: Sorry. I don't know an answer apart from that... Post another answer if you find an easier way. I would be interested in that too.